# How can I prove statistical significance between model results?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I'm kind of knew in statistics, and I'm working in a time predictor related to process events. As an accuracy measurement, I'm using MAE, but my advisor asked me to use a statistical test to validate the statistical significance of the results I got with my model compared with the baseline models. He suggested the F-test and Kruskal-Wallis, but I lack in experience on the subject of statistical tests. Which one I should be using to validate, or should I be using another test?

My data looks like this:

[image]

And the distribution is as the following picture

[image: Distribution of prediction results in seconds]

Comment: So are "Predicted times" some vector you created based on "Ground Truth Times"? How exactly did you build the prediction and what, in simple words, would you like to claim about what you've done so far? Contrary to what your advisor saying, a hypothesis test cannot be done without an exact hypothesis. It doesn't seem like claiming that your prediction is *different* from ground truth could possibly be what you want to do.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you want to test?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, the predicted times column is the prediction result that comes from a LSTM based prediction. Thus, I have the results from 2 models that uses different features and validate the prediction results using a statistical test to see if the difference in prediction is statistically relevant.